# Get data from one table with nested relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new in DB and I have a table *topics* and in this table, I have a foreign key *master_topic_id* and this foreign key is related to the same table *topics* column id.
Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.topics (
id bigserial NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
published_at timestamp NULL,
master_topic_id int8 NULL,
CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT t_master_topic_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (master_topic_id) REFERENCES topics(id
);
```

I write a query - SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = 10. But if this record has *master_topic_id* I need to get data by *master_topic_id* too.
I tried to do it by using JOIN, but join just concat records, but I need to have data from *master_topic_id* as new row.
Any help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing:

```
select t.*
from topics t
where t.id = 10 or
      exists (select 1
              from topics t2
              where t2.master_topic_id = t.id and t2.id = 10
             );
```

However, you might just want:

```
where 10 in (id, master_topic_id)
```

Comment: no. for example I have topic with id=10 and master_topic_id=9 . I need to get 2 records - with id 10 and 9

Comment: @VolodymyrZavada . . . That was my intention for the first query.  I fixed it so the intention and code are better aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` in your `where` condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics 
WHERE id = 10 
or master_topic_id = 10
```

you can use `union all` as well

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics 
WHERE id = 10 

union all

SELECT * 
FROM topics 
WHERE master_topic_id = 10
```